# What is causing my images to not load initially in safari. All other browsers seem to work fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css, safari

I am currently using the 3d cardflip method on my website and it is working perfectly in Firefox, IE, as well as the IE downgrades I have for older browsers.  My issue is arising from the fact that it seems that all Apple iOS devices and Safari will not load the images and information on the cards on the initial load of the page but only when a hard reload or a simple reload of the page is performed.  I have tried everything I can think of to fix the issue and I have not been able to find any information regarding the issue either.  Any help would be gladly appreciated! The page that is not working is http://www.paytonandsam.com/about_sam.html

Comment: It's working fine for me in Safari 5.1.5 & Mobile Safari on IOS 5.0.

Comment: Can you post your Safari version and any mods/plugins/extensions (w/e the iOS word for them)?

Comment: I tested on Safari Version 6.0.2 (8536.26.17) and loads correctly

Comment: Works on Safari 6.0.2 (7536.26.17).

Comment: Also works on Safari 6.0.3 (8536.28.10)

Answer (score 1):

Please test this website on Safari Version 5.1.5, 6.0.2,6.0.3 i.e. a higher version of Safari browser. Because now safari browser is faster and flexible than the older version.